# Writing a file with nodejs into a specific direoctory and upload it to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fs, multer

Hello I'm working on a file upload using nodejs, express and mongodb for the database
this is my **POST API** to create a new file in my database using multer

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');
    function Filetostring(){ 
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
        // Find returns the first element that matches our criteria
        const step = arr.filter((step , idx)=> {
            if (step.includes("step")) {
             console.log(step);             //this gives me the first result I need
    
             return true;
    
            }
            return false;
         }); 
       let stepss = JSON.stringify(step)
       let newString = stepss.replace(/[\[\]\'\s]/g, ' ');
       let newString2 = newString.replace(/"/g, '');
       let newString3 = newString2.replace(/#step/g, '');
       let newString4 = newString3.replace(/,/g, '\n');

       return newString4;
     }

     let newName = JSON.stringify(req.files[0].filename)
     let newName1 = newName.replace(/"/g, '');
     let newName2 = newName1.replace(/.robot/g, '');
     let steps = Filetostring()
     console.log(steps)

    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: newName2,
        upload: req.files[0].filename ,
        run : steps,
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    //const file = req.file;
    console.log(req.files[0].filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("errorrrrr") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

The file upload is working fine but I want to add a function to write a new file instead of uploading an existing file
For example I write text using my form (let's say i fill the variable **step1**) and it gets stored into **./uploads/name.txt**

I saw that there is a **fs** function called **fs.writeFile** but I don't know how to properly implement it so it automaticly save the text that i put in my variable into a file

I tried this but it gives me an "errorrrrr":

```
upload: fs.writeFile('./uploads/'+req.body.name+'.robot', req.body.step1 , function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;               console.log('Results Received');
          }),
```

If I use :

```
upload: fs.writeFile('./uploads/aa.robot', 'hello' , function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;               console.log('Results Received');
          }),
```

I get an error in adding a new Testcase but the file get uploaded **aa.robot** and inside it is actually the text i needed **hello**

Here is how my API looks now:

```
router.post('/create2', (req, res) => {
     
    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        upload: fs.writeFile('./uploads/aa.robot', 'hello' , function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;               console.log('Results Received');
          }),
        
        run : req.body.run,
        
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("errorrrrr") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want to write Testcase document you created using uploaded file as another .json file, am I correct?

Comment: No I want to have an option to write a test case and export it as a file .txt or .robot
for now i just can upload existing files

Comment: Oh okay, then you have several ways of getting the 'write as file' option, for example you can ask your client to add this option to request body like ``"save": true`` or query parameter like ``?save=true``. You will need to implement this logic into your route handler and then save (write) file to the path you want to store it. I can help you with the writing part, option part is depending on your choice.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post with what i tried (just making a try) it's giving me an error but at the same time the file "results.txt" gets exported successfully

Comment: Good. What error are you getting? You can select use ``JSON.stringify(tc.toObject())`` as data parameter for your ``fs.writeFile()`` implementation, so you can write your Testcase document as a string into your .txt file. Was that all you want?

Comment: I edited my reply again sorry for bothering you, the error i get is : "The \"data\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined"

Comment: It's fine, im here to help as much as I can. Seems like what you have passed as data parameter to ``fs.writeFile()`` was undefined. I think it was a string before your last edit, I'm not sure why that error was thrown. Does your current implementation with ``req.body.step1`` as data parameter work well without an error?

Comment: Yeah it's usually works fine, can you see the 2nd part I added without the 'req.body' variables and see why my testcase doesnt get added to the database even if the file gets successfully exported as 'aa.robo'

Comment: Oh, yeah now I see the 2nd part. Can you update your current post route handler implementation with your ``fs.writeFile()` please`? I need to see the full implementation to have an idea. Currently it doesn't give much hint.

Comment: I added it at the end thank you, can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: I have posted an answer depending on what I understand and what should be done with your implementation. You can check it. If you have question about it, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct implementation of your POST route handler. What you are doing wrong is you are trying to set value of upload field in your Testcase document as a function that is `fs.writeFile()`. If you have a correct Mongoose schame for validating your Testcase document, then this value of upload field will be failing. But of course if that is not what you want, but I suppose it is not.

This is the correct implementation of your POST route handler:

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');
    function Filetostring(){ 
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
        // Find returns the first element that matches our criteria
        const step = arr.filter((step , idx)=> {
            if (step.includes("step")) {
             console.log(step);             //this gives me the first result I need
    
             return true;
    
            }
            return false;
        }); 
        let stepss = JSON.stringify(step)
        let newString = stepss.replace(/[\[\]\'\s]/g, ' ');
        let newString2 = newString.replace(/"/g, '');
        let newString3 = newString2.replace(/#step/g, '');
        let newString4 = newString3.replace(/,/g, '\n');

        return newString4;
     }

    let newName = JSON.stringify(req.files[0].filename)
    let newName1 = newName.replace(/"/g, '');
    let newName2 = newName1.replace(/.robot/g, '');
    let steps = Filetostring();

    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: newName2,
        upload: req.files[0].filename,
        run : steps,
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });

    let saveFlag = req.query.save && req.query.save.trim().toLowerCase() === 'true'
        ? true
        : false;
    
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("errorrrrr") }
        else {
            if(saveFlag) {
                let data = JSON.stringify(doc.toObject());
                fs.writeFile(`./uploads/filename.txt`, data, (err) => {
                    if(err) res.status(500).send(err.message);
                    else res.status(200).send(doc);
                });
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(doc);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here I set `upload: req.files[0].filename` like in your original implementation, it will take the name of the file has been uploaded to your storage. Then after a few lines, I have created `saveFlag` variable to check if your client wants you to save the Testcase document or not. At the bottom, in the callback of `tc.save((err, doc) => {...})` I have implemented a `fs.writeFile()` function which is depending on query parameter named `save`. Your requests to your API should be something like `POST http://hostname:port/api/router/create?save=true`. It's data is stringified Testcase document. You can change that data with what you want to write in your file.